# OnClick Function Get Next Record PHP AJAX MYSQL

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am getting stuck with an example I found on SO about this very topic.
See original article: [How do I show next result in MySQL on "onclick" in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3681407/how-do-i-show-next-result-in-mysql-on-onclick-in-javascript)

I followed this example to the T, with the exception of using some updated functions.  Anyway, I am getting stuck on one step, was hoping someone could explain.

within the jquery below, the code is setting $number and then passing number in the POST action to the php file.  My problem is is that when echo 'count', it echos "$number".  I am not sure why it is not passing an actual number such as "0" rather than the string "$number".  I am probably doing something seriously wrong, but not sure what is going on.

**jquery**

```
$(function(){
  $('#showMore').click(function(event) {
     event.preventDefault();
     $number = $('.result').size();

    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "getNext.php",
       data: "count=$number",
       success: function(results){
         $('#results').append(results);
       }
     });

  });
```

**PHP**
I am passing count into a variable so that I can use it in a query, like so:

```
$pst = $_POST['count'];
```

**SQL**

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tablename LIMIT $pst,1";
```

I went ahead and captured the error I am receiving (see below) - as mentioned previously it is inserting "$number" instead of an actual number.

"Fatal error: Query Failed! SQL: SELECT * FROM tablename LIMIT $number,1

any help would be much appreciated

Comment: If you learn how to see requests/responds, you could quickly see that you are not passing correct data via ajax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

problem is you are sending count as string which is $number in your case.

your data should be

```
data: {"count":$number}, //notice `"`
```

send it as object.

or

```
$data:"count=" + $number,
```

concate the var

i prefer data as object which is more readable.

Comment: Thanks, your first example worked for me {"count":$number}  I already had the second example input in my ajax as per the last comment in the original post but that did not work.

Answer (score 3):

Try changing this line:

```
data: "count=$number",
```

To this

```
data: "count=" + $number,
```

Javascript doesn't "read" strings for variables like php does, so you need to concat the value manually.