# using ajax url to call function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Hopefully I can ask this correctly cuz I know what I want it to do but can't seem to find any answers from searching.

I have a func.php page where I have all my functions and I want ajax to use one function from that page.

func.php

```
function toptable()
{ 
  echo"something happens in here";
}
```

index.php

```
<?php include 'func.php'; ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
function check_username() {
  uname=document.getElementById("username").value;
  var params = "user_id="+uname;
  var url = "topoftable()";
  $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: url,
      dataType: 'html',
      data: params,
      beforeSend: function() {
        document.getElementById("right").innerHTML= 'checking'  ;
      },
      complete: function() {

      },
      success: function(html) {
        document.getElementById("right").innerHTML= html ;
      }
  });

}

</script>
```

Make sense?

Comment: Is your Top Table function a PHP or Javascript function? You are including the function outside of your <script type="text/javascript">.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using JQuery Ajax to call a php function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2842776/using-jquery-ajax-to-call-a-php-function)

Comment: not 100% clear what you are asking

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's not working like that.

Your AJAX request should look something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    //some even that will run ajax request - for example click on a button

    var uname = $('#username').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'func.php', //this should be url to your PHP file
        dataType: 'html',
        data: {func: 'toptable', user_id: uname},
        beforeSend: function() {
            $('#right').html('checking');
        },
        complete: function() {},
        success: function(html) {
            $('#right').html(html);
        }
    });

});
```

And your `func.php`:

```
function toptable()
{
  echo 'something happens in here';
}

//here you can do some "routing"
$func = $_POST['func']; //remember to escape it

switch ($func) {
    case 'toptable':
        toptable();
        break;
    default:
        //function not found, error or something
        break;
}
```

Also check that I change `document.getElementById` to jQuery selector `$('#...')`.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is server side, JS is client side.
You need to call the PHP script in the ajax request, not the function.

Something like

```
[...]
 var url = "func.php";
 $.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       url: url,
[...]
```

func.php

```
<?php
function toptable()
{ 
  echo "something happens in here";
}
toptable();
?>
```

In this case, the `html` argument in the success handler of the ajax request will be equal to `"something happens in here"`.

Answer (score 0):

*Make sense?* - no. You can't mix PHP (a server-side technology) with Javascript (client-side). You can use AJAX to ask a server to perform some function for you, but not by using the function name as a URL. You should create a PHP page to accept your AJAX request, perform the function and return the result, and use the URL of that page in your AJAX request