# How can I get a list of cities based on the selected state?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Why is my AJAX call not passing data to the given URL? It is not showing any errors either. How can I get a city list based on the selected state?

```html
<label>State</label>
<select name="state" id="state">
  <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your state</option>
  <?php foreach($states as $state){
    echo '<option value="'.$state['state_id'].'">'.$state['state_name'].'</option>';
  } ?>
</select><br><br>

<label>Aperture Place</label>
<select name="aperture_place" class="city">
  <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your city</option>
</select><br><br>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('#state').change(function() {
    var id = jQuery(this).val();
    //alert(id);
    jQuery.ajax({
      type: 'post',
      url: "<?php echo base_url().'routes/get_city' ?>",
      data: 'id=' + id,
      success: function(result) {
        alert(result);
        //jQuery('.city').html(result);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```php
public function get_city() 
{
  $id = $_POST['id'];
  $query = $this -> common -> select_data_by_id('city', 'state', $id, '*', '');
  print_r($query);
  exit();
  echo '<option value="" disabled selected>Choose your city</option>';
  foreach($query as $place) {
    echo '<option value="'.$place['city_name'].'">'.$place['city_name'].'</option>';
  }
}
```

Comment: What data is returned to the request? What does the `alert()` show? Are there any errors server side? Is the AJAX request returning an error?

Comment: nothing to show into alert

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/19869313/8769830

Comment: What do you get with: `$id = $_POST['id'];echo $id;exit();`

Comment: Does the php function work/do anything if you call it directly?

Comment: `Why is my AJAX call not passing data to the given URL?` ...your code should pass the value correctly. Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/zs4bgwve/ - if you watch the request in the network tab it passed "id: 1" when you select "State 1". Of course in the demo the request fails because I made up the URL, but it demonstrates that it should be _sending_ the data. This assumes of course that the `<option` tags you're generating have a valid ID in the "value" attribute. We can't see your finished HTML, so it's hard to be sure. But the idea is right.

Comment: Now...if you're not getting the _response_ you expected, that's a different matter. Again watch your browser's Network tools and Console to see what comes back from the server, and if it contains any errors. Unless the call to the server returns a "200 OK" response then the "success" function in the $.ajax call will never be executed. We cannot tell exactly what your PHP will do because we can only see your get_city() function. We can't see how or where it's called.

Comment: data: {id : id} is not working

Comment: "not working" isn't an error message or problem statement, sorry. It tells us nothing useful. You need to find out what **is** happening instead, that's far more important for solving your issue. Check the debugging suggestions I made in my comments above and report back to us on the result (assuming you don't already solve the issue when you investigate like this). These are the most basic debugging tasks and skills you should already be using before asking for help. If you don't learn to debug using your browser-side and server-side tools then you'll always have basic issues with your code.

Comment: You're also **ignoring** any ajax errors: add `jQuery.ajax({ ... }).fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) { console.log(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown); });` updated @ADyson 's fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/shuvmegj/

Comment: console is display like this,http://localhost/busbooking/admincp/routes/get_city 403 (Forbidden)
send @ jquery.min.js:2
ajax @ jquery.min.js:2
(anonymous) @ (index):115
dispatch @ jquery.min.js:2
y.handle @ jquery.min.js:2
ListPicker._handleMouseUp
(index):123 {readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: ƒ, getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ, setRequestHeader: ƒ, overrideMimeType: ƒ, …} "error" "Forbidden"

Comment: there you go then. I assume you googled what a HTTP 403 error means, if you didn't already know? "Forbidden" is hopefully quite clear in any case without googling! You need to resolve why your server is returning a "Forbidden" response. Perhaps the URL is wrong, or maybe you didn't supply some authentication credentials (although 401 would be more likely in that case), or maybe some file permissions are wrong. It's likely a server-side issue. Not much we can do to directly help with that based on the information provided here, unfortunately.